# Arduino to Python by using Serial Communication

Tags: python, serial-communication

Hi if I send Arduino to Python by using serial communication. Let assume that gives

```
1111
2222
3333

1111
2222
3333
```

like this.

This is part of my python code.

```
data = arduino.readline()
str = data[:-2].decode()
```

I wonder how can I store that 111,2222,3333 value right away??? 
For example

```
data = arduino.readline()
a= ~~~
b=~~~~
c=~~~~~
```

and when I print out a,b,c I want to see the value a=1111 b=2222 c=3333
Do you have any solution? I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can use a dictionary to store the values

Comment: @Rakesh if you are not busy, can you explain it by code?? I really appreciate it thx!

Comment: @Rakesh can you check it...?